# Copy Custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I bought a theme and it came with a custom post type called teachers.
It has a bunch of custom fields associated with it.

I want to copy that custom post type and make a duplicate of it for secondaryteachers.

I searched in my functions folder but did not find anything that creates the post type.
Where would i find the settings that were used when I uploaded and installed the theme? Which file would it be located in?

Comment: Try searching in both the theme's folder and the plugins folder for the string `register_post_type(`. themes are sometimes shipped with additional plugins, and the code for the new post type could be in a custom plugin.

Comment: hey can i know who did u achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install WordPress plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/screenshots/

set plugin setting in tour post type and "`Clone`" "`Copy`" your post type.

Comment: Will this duplicate post make me a new post type under a different name? or just duplicate the posts itself?

Comment: Sorry i can't understand. please explain you what to do ?

Comment: I need to duplicate the post type, not the posts itself, but I am unable to find it in the files where they were set up originally.